# Writing the ros pub command inside the launch file

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a command line command:

```
rostopic pub /rec_pose_as/goal path_exam/RecordOdomActionGoal "header:
  seq: 0
  stamp:
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: ''
goal_id:
  stamp:
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  id: ''
goal: {}"
```

I want to use a launch file to run this command, so I do the following:

```
<node pkg='rostopic' type='rostopic' name='some_arbitary_name' args='pub /rec_pose_as/goal path_exam/RecordOdomActionGoal 
"header:
  seq: 0
  stamp:
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: ""
goal_id:
  stamp:
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  id: ""
goal: {}"' />
```

But I get the error

```
rostopic: error: Argument error: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "<string>", line 1, column 14:
    header:   seq: 0   stamp:     secs: 0     nse ...
```

The error appears to come at seq: (the arrow points at colon)

What should be done? Would be grateful to any help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355399/writing-the-ros-pub-command-inside-the-launch-file/) by [hrushi19](https://answers.ros.org/users/50003/hrushi19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2020-06-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hrushi19](https://answers.ros.org/users/50003/hrushi19/) on 2020-06-20**:
Actually I found a way to escape this error, I copied the command to a bash script and ran the bash script from the command line, using https://answers.ros.org/question/51474/can-i-run-a-bash-script-using-roslaunch/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to pass the arguments in yaml format using `{}` instead of multiple lines:

The code for the `arg` must all go on one line:

```
<arg name="my_pose" default="'{header: {seq: 0, stamp: {secs: 0, nsecs: 0}, frame_id: ''}, goal_id: {stamp: {secs: 0.0, nsecs: 0.0}, id: ''}, goal: {}'"/>
<node pkg="rostopic"
  type="rostopic"
  name="some_arbitary_name"
  args="pub /rec_pose_as/goal path_exam/RecordOdomActionGoal $(arg my_pose)"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [eeppii](https://answers.ros.org/users/69135/eeppii/) with karma: 116 on 2021-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0